# Local variable not initialized, but still program compiling

Tags: java, variables, local

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("started");
       //func();

   }

   static void func(){
       double d;
       int i;
       System.out.println("d ="+d);
       System.out.println("i ="+i);
   }

}
```

That fact that I know is *Local Variables must be initialized before they use*. Here `d` and `i` are local variables. You can see that I have not initialized them. **Why I can still compile the program and able to run this?**

If I un-commment the *func()*, then I get a compilation error.

Comment: No that doesn't compile. Some IDEs may use tricks to execute uncompilable code (as long as the uncompilable part is not "run") but if you compile it with javac you will get an error.

Comment: It still does not compile.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan, As per my experience, It's not possible. you must have to initialize local variable. please, check twice.

Comment: If you really can run this, where is the output it produces?

Comment: Hey, what the hell people are doing here. no body supplies positive answer, instead of it, i request to all please reply if you have Anwer only otherwise reply via comment only.

Comment: To all closevoters. This question is not unreproducible and also isn't a typo. OP knows very well that there's a compilation error. He's asking why he can sometimes run it and sometimes not.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha *When* and *if* the OP answers the questions he's been asked here, his question will be eligible for serious consideration.

Comment: If you can compile this and run it, please post output of this:
`javap -c Test.class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `javac` to compile it, it does not compile:

```
stephen@blackbox tmp]$ cat > Test.java
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("started");
       //func();

   }

   static void func(){
       double d;
       int i;
       System.out.println("d ="+d);
       System.out.println("i ="+i);
   }

}
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ javac Test.java 
Test.java:12: error: variable d might not have been initialized
       System.out.println("d ="+d);
                                ^
Test.java:13: error: variable i might not have been initialized
       System.out.println("i ="+i);
                                ^
2 errors
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$
```

---

My guess is that you are using an IDE, and you have at some point in the past told the IDE that it is OK to attempt to run a program with compilation errors.  That is implemented by "compiling" methods with compilation errors into bytecodes that throw an exception when called.  When you comment out the call to the faulty method, it doesn't get called ... naturally ... and the exception doesn't get thrown.

But the bottom line is that you DID get a compilation error.  You just told the IDE to ignore it.

---

The solution is obvious.  Fix the compilation error.

Comment: it's not Solution man, already everybody reply on question's comment. please, post Answer only.

Comment: It is the solution.  In fact it is the only solution.  And it is an answer.  Man.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't compile. Here the output from my compilation try:

```
Test.java:12: error: variable d might not have been initialized
   System.out.println("d ="+d);
                            ^
Test.java:13: error: variable i might not have been initialized
   System.out.println("i ="+i);
                            ^
2 errors
```